# How can we verify that the system $Ax=b$ is equivalent to $A^{T}Ax=A^{T}b$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations, numerical-linear-algebra

Let $A \in \mathcal{M}(\mathbb{R})$ be an invertible matrix, $b \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$.  How can we verify that the system $Ax=b$ is equivalent to $A^{T}Ax=A^{T}b$?

Is $A^{T}A$ a positive definite symmetric matrix?

Comment: What are your thoughts abiut it and what have you tried?

Comment: Every solution to the first system is automatically a solution to the second system, and so all that is required is to show that you do not get any new solutions, and for that you just need to check that the rank of $A^TA$ is the same as the rank of $A$.

Comment: If $A$ is invertible so is $A^T.$

Comment: MathJax'ed text? Why?

Answer (score 3):

There are two distinct questions (you should have posted them separately).

$Ax=b$ is equivalent to $A^TAx=A^Tb$ because $A^T$ is invertible (its inverse is $(A^{-1})^T$).

The symmetric matrix $A^TA$ is [positive definite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Definite_matrix) because for all $x\ne0$, $x^T(A^TA)x=\|Ax\|^2>0$.

Comment: Thank you could you clarify more please if it is possible.

Comment: What precisely is unclear to you?